# How do you find a series of characters in python?

Tags: python

To be more specific, given a string as such:
`XOOOO.XO.`

I need to see how many instances of the format "X", followed by any number of "O"'s, followed by a "." is there in the string.

I also would need to get the index of the period.

Examples of strings I would need to find:

```
XO.
XOO.
XOOO.
```

Non-examples:

```
X.O
X..O
X.OOOO.
OX.
```

Comment: Take a look at `re.findall`. Write some code, and if you get stuck, then please ask a specific question, explaining where you're stuck.

Comment: Some online tool like [pythex](https://pythex.org/) could help you to try faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way you can also find the indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import re

def findPattern(s):
    m = re.findall(r'(X)+(O)+(.)', s)
    return len(m)
```